# Skipping a null element in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
// Make Home page text zoomable


//Create an object that stores the initial values of your button and a variable which holds the state of it.

// Set an intial state of 0
var state = 0;

// Set the original font sizes as a variable
var original = {};
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("introductionheading").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("homeparagraph1").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("homeparagraph2").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("homeparagraph3").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("homeparagraph4").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("productgalleryheading").style.fontSize;

function clickToZoomHome() {

//Checking what the state is, if it's 0 - change the font size and set the state to 1, if it's 1, set the font size back to the original and set the state back to 0
  if (state == 0) {
    document.getElementById("introductionheading").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph1").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph2").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph3").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph4").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("productgalleryheading").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    state = 1;
      
  } else {
      
    document.getElementById("introductionheading").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph1").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph2").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph3").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph4").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("productgalleryheading").style.fontSize =original.fontSize;
    state = 0;
  }
}


// Make Kitchen page text zoomable

var state = 0;

var originalfontsize = {};
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("kitchenheading").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph1").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph2").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph3").style.fontSize;

function clickToZoomKitchen() {

  if (state == 0) {
    document.getElementById("kitchenheading").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph1").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph2").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph3").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    state = 1;
      
  } else {
      
    document.getElementById("kitchenheading").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph1").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph2").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph3").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    state = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
    <section class="introduction">
        <div class="row" id="introductionheading">
            <h2>Introduction</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">

                <h3>Heading 1</h3>
                <p id="homeparagraph1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            </div>
            <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">

                <h3>Heading 2</h3>

                <p id="homeparagraph2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            </div>
            <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">

                <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                <p id="homeparagraph3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            </div>
            <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">

                <h3>Heading 4</h3>
                <p id="homeparagraph4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        
    <footer>

        <div class='row'>

            <div>
                <button id="zoomable" onclick="clickToZoomHome()">Click here to change the size of the text</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to create a button that makes the text on screen bigger when clicked, and then back to the original size when clicked again. Here's what I have:

```
// Make Home page text zoomable


//Create an object that stores the initial values of your button and a variable which holds the state of it.

// Set an intial state of 0
var state = 0;

// Set the original font sizes as a variable
var original = {};
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("introductionheading").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("homeparagraph1").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("homeparagraph2").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("homeparagraph3").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("homeparagraph4").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("productgalleryheading").style.fontSize;

function clickToZoomHome() {

//Checking what the state is, if it's 0 - change the font size and set the state to 1, if it's 1, set the font size back to the original and set the state back to 0
  if (state == 0) {
    document.getElementById("introductionheading").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph1").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph2").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph3").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph4").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("productgalleryheading").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    state = 1;

  } else {

    document.getElementById("introductionheading").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph1").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph2").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph3").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("homeparagraph4").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("productgalleryheading").style.fontSize =original.fontSize;
    state = 0;
  }
}


// Make Kitchen page text zoomable

var state = 0;

var originalfontsize = {};
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("kitchenheading").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph1").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph2").style.fontSize;
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph3").style.fontSize;

function clickToZoomKitchen() {

  if (state == 0) {
    document.getElementById("kitchenheading").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph1").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph2").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph3").style.fontSize = "20pt";
    state = 1;

  } else {

    document.getElementById("kitchenheading").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph1").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph2").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("kitchenparagraph3").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
    state = 0;
  }
}
```

My issue is that on the Home page (or the first page), it works fine. But on the Kitchen page (or any other page other than the home) it will make the text bigger, but then when you click it again, it won't work. The console shows an error that says it's because it can't read the style of null for line 11, which is the line that stores the introduction heading font size. This id is not found on the Kitchen page which is why it's null.

How can I get around this? Any advice or tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it would be nice to have some testable code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you really mean to use the same `original.fontsize` property for all the elements? Shouldn't it be something like `original.introductionheading`, `original.homeparagraph1`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If the element might not exist, you need to check for that.
Change

```
original.fontSize = document.getElementById("introductionheading").style.fontSize;
```

to

```
var introheading = document.getElementById("introductionheading");
if (introheading) {
    original.fontsize = introheading.style.fontSize;
}
```

and similar when changing the style. Change

```
document.getElementById("introductionheading").style.fontSize = "20pt";
```

to

```
if (introheading) {
    introheading.style.fontSize = "20pt";
}
```

and

```
document.getElementById("kitchenheading").style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
```

to

```
if (introheading) {
    introheading.style.fontSize = original.fontSize;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I'm a little unsure on where I would actually use this within my script. I understand that you're checking if it exists, but not sure where to actually place it. Would it be done within function clickToZoomHome?

Comment: You place it where you have the assignment that's getting the error.